# UICollectionViewCell to UIButton Focus in tvOS

Tags: ios, tvos, apple-tv

I have a UICollectionView which contains 12-13 UICollectionViewCells. I can easily focus on the UICollectionViewCells and everything works. There is a UIButton outside the UICollectionView. If I am on the first cell or the second cell and I swipe up then I can easily focus on the UIButton. When I am on the third cell then I am not able to move the focus to the UIButton. Any ideas what is going on?

[image]

Answer (score 18):

You should use a UIFocusGuide that encompasses the UIButton you want to focus. Make the UIFocusGuide as wide as the collectionView and tall enough to cover the button. Make the preferredFocusView the button.

```
  UIFocusGuide *topButtonFocusGuide = [[UIFocusGuide alloc] init];
  topButtonFocusGuide.preferredFocusedView = myButton;
  [self.view addLayoutGuide:topButtonFocusGuide];

  [self.view addConstraints:@[
    [topButtonFocusGuide.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:myButton.topAnchor],
    [topButtonFocusGuide.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:myCollectionView.topAnchor],
    [topButtonFocusGuide.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:myCollectionView.leadingAnchor],
    [topButtonFocusGuide.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:myCollectionView.widthAnchor],
  ]];
```

Comment: Thanks Jess - this was driving me nuts. Note that if you have a problem using this then it could be because one of your anchor points is embedded in another view. I had a collection view inside a scroll view and using the collection view bottom as my top anchor point didn't work. Changing this to the scroll view bottom worked.

Comment: Works like a charm ! Thanks.

Comment: Hi Jess, I have another issue. If I have button at right instead of left and if I have only one row collection view I can't able make collection view focusable. Any solution for this ?

Comment: @Vijay_07 that's probably worth opening a new stack question. Not sure off the bat.

Answer (score 2):

Jess Bowers solution is almost there but Xcode says `UIButton`s doesn't have `topAnchor` property and the solution given by Jess doesn't work for me.

For me, the solution was to create a huge view with the same width as the `UICollectionView` on top of it. See picture.

[image]

The code will be this:

```
 UIFocusGuide *topButtonFocusGuide = [[UIFocusGuide alloc] init];
  topButtonFocusGuide.preferredFocusedView = myButton;
  [self.view addLayoutGuide:topButtonFocusGuide];

  [self.view addConstraints:@[
    [topButtonFocusGuide.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:transparentView.topAnchor],
    [topButtonFocusGuide.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:transparentView.bottomAnchor],
    [topButtonFocusGuide.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:transparentView.leadingAnchor],
    [topButtonFocusGuide.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:transparentView.widthAnchor],
  ]];
```

Comment: UIButton is a subclass of UIControl which is a subclass of UIView. https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/ Also look at the Apple sample which uses topAnchor on a button. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/samplecode/UICatalogFortvOS/Listings/UIKitCatalog_FocusGuidesViewController_swift.html

Comment: Ok but Xcode says buttons have no topAnchor and unfortunately Jess' solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: Something else is wrong. I just typed in a name of my button, typed .top and hit escape and the autocomplete showed me topAnchor. Current Xcode. Also, Jess' solution doesn't work for me either. I examine the guide's frame in a breakpoint and it looks right. But it has no effect.

Comment: That is very strange. Anyway it is not working for me.

Comment: yeah that's strange. I've used this technique many times. UIButton definitely has a topAnchor. Possibly there is something specific and different about the setup. Might be helpful to post more code in the question and i'd be happy to give feedback. Certain assumptions i made may not be true for your case. UIFocusGuide and layout guide are meant to eliminate the need for dummy views like you've got there. But they do work.

Comment: I am not sure what it is, but your method is simply not working for me.

Comment: The Xcode debugger returns error: property 'topAnchor' not found on object of type 'UIButton *'
error: 1 errors parsing expression
when I po self.selectAllButton.topAnchor but works when I  po [self.selectAllButton topAnchor]. Weird stuff.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3.0**

Jess Bower's answer was huge help to me & saved a lot of time.

Here's what worked with Swift 3 & tvOS 10. One now has to use `preferredFocusEnvironments`. In ViewDidLoad()

```
        self.view.addLayoutGuide(focusGuide)
        self.focusGuide.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.buttonAbove.topAnchor).isActive = true
        self.focusGuide.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.CollectionView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        self.focusGuide.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.CollectionView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        self.focusGuide.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.CollectionView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        self.focusGuide.preferredFocusEnvironments = [self.buttonAbove]
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the issues I was facing involved using a UINavigationController for the landing pages to push detail ViewControllers onto the stack when an item is selected.

I put a breakpoint inside the UIButton's **canBecomeFocused** override, and using this quick little extension asked the button why it is not focusable.

```
extension UIView {
    func whyNotFucusable () {
        print(self.perform(Selector(("_whyIsThisViewNotFocusable"))).takeUnretainedValue())
    }
}
```

I kept receiving the following error trying to debug....

```
ISSUE: This view may not be focusable because other views or focus guides are occluding it.
```

First of all I looked up in the dictionary what the heck occluding meant....

```
verb, formal, technical 
     - stop, close up, or obstruct (an opening, orifice, or passage).
```

The question now was what view is obstructing my UIButton???

I quickly unwrapped the UI in the visual debugger, and there was a clear view on top of my UIButtons. Inspecting the view I found out that **Unlike** iOS, where the nagivationBar has a default system background color, tvOS's implementation has a clear default color. I realized that I didn't hide the nav bar, and in return it was obstructing my buttons.

I did the following, and it fixed all my issues :)

```
navController.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
```

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score -2):

Use :

override weak var preferredFocusedView: UIView? {
   get {
return segmentedControl
    } }