# UICollectionView and UIFocusGuide[s]

Tags: uicollectionview, tvos

I have a collection view with a varying number of cells. Under the collectionview is a button. When the focus in on a cell in line vertically with the button, I can move focus from the cell to the button. When the focus is on a cell that's not in a vertical line, I cannot give the button focus.

Sounds like a job for UIFocusGuide! The Apple example shows two buttons and using the focus guide as the invisible "view" for focus. My actual question is: how do you do that with a collection view? Add focus guide[s] as cells?

Has anyone used a Collectionview with focus guides and can offer advice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UICollectionViewCell to UIButton Focus in tvOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33240105/uicollectionviewcell-to-uibutton-focus-in-tvos)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33240105/uicollectionviewcell-to-uibutton-focus-in-tvos