# UICollectionViewCell to UIButton Focus

Tags: swift, tvos, apple-tv

My problem is similar to the problem described in [UICollectionViewCell to UIButton Focus in tvOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33240105/uicollectionviewcell-to-uibutton-focus-in-tvos)
but my button is below the `UICollectionView`. I tried adding focus guide but I must have done something wrong.

```
let topButtonFocusGuide = UIFocusGuide()
topButtonFocusGuide.preferredFocusedView = myButton
self.view.addLayoutGuide(topButtonFocusGuide)

self.view.addConstraint(topButtonFocusGuide.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(myCollectionView.bottomAnchor))
self.view.addConstraint(topButtonFocusGuide.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.bottomAnchor))
self.view.addConstraint(topButtonFocusGuide.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(myCollectionView.leadingAnchor))
self.view.addConstraint(topButtonFocusGuide.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(myCollectionView.widthAnchor))
```

I get this error:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
CostomLayout[18448:888102] The view hierarchy is not prepared for the 
constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fb9e3c5e060 V:[UICollectionView:0x7fb9e501ac00]-(0)-[UIFocusGuide:0x7fb9e3c5b8b0'']>
```

Comment: are you sure your UICollectionview is added to view before adding constraints?

Comment: I have this before the focus guide code                                                               `let myCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: collectionViewFlowLayout)`

Comment: are you adding self.view.addSubView(myCollectionView)?

Comment: It gives me a different error. I am quite new to swift and the whole thing.

Comment: I have updated my answer, but I think you need to learn more about the basics, so go to apple docs and read more about the basic things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don't have `CollectionView` in view hierarchy, means you have not added `collectionView` as `subView` of `view`.
Please make sure you are adding `collectionView` as `subview` before applying any constraints. You can do this like below

```
self.view.addSubView(myCollectionView)
```

Add this like of code before

```
self.view.addConstraint(topButtonFocusGuide.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(myCollectionView.bottomAnchor))
```

**Update:**
The new error is because you are not registering cell with  UICollectionView, after creating collection view object add this line.

```
[myCollectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

I think you need to read more about collection view, [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/78550/beginning-ios-collection-views-swift-part-1) is a great tutorial to get started with `UICollectionView`

[Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/) on this topic

Comment: `2016-06-22 09:42:35.092 CostomLayout[25898:947580] *** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.60.315/UICollectionView.m:3995
2016-06-22 09:42:35.095 CostomLayout[25898:947580] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'`

Comment: This error is because you are not registering nib/cell type with collection view