# UIFocusGuide doesn't work on UICollectionView in tvOS

Tags: uicollectionview, tvos, apple-tv

Basing on this post:
[UICollectionViewCell to UIButton Focus in tvOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33240105/uicollectionviewcell-to-uibutton-focus-in-tvos), I'm adding a `UIFocusGuide` so when the user are on the right of the `collectionview`, can select the button on left-buttom.

Using this code:

```
focusGuide = UIFocusGuide();
focusGuide.preferredFocusedView = btClick
view.addLayoutGuide(focusGuide)
focusGuide.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(collectionView.topAnchor).active = true
focusGuide.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(btClick.bottomAnchor).active = true
focusGuide.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(collectionView.leadingAnchor).active = true
focusGuide.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(collectionView.widthAnchor).active = true
```

In my example I added a usefull [code](https://github.com/jack-cox-captech/LayoutGuideExamples) created by Jack Cox that shows the 'invisible' layout guides, and everything seems good because the layout begin on the top of the `collectionView` and ends on the bottom of the button.

But it doesn't works, the button only can be selected if the user are on the left of `collectionView`, on this image you can only going to button from item 1 and item 6.

[image]

I've made a little example on github [here](https://github.com/garanda21/TVOSCollectionViewUIFocusGuide), I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have already figured out, the mistake was to create the focus with the entire size of the `collectionView` now I've created a focus guide just below the `collectionView` and set `preferredFocusedView`to the button.

Using this code:

```
focusGuide = UIFocusGuide();
focusGuide.preferredFocusedView = btClick
view.addLayoutGuide(focusGuide)

//Modified the size of the UIFocusGuide
focusGuide.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(btClick.topAnchor).active = true   
focusGuide.rightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(collectionView.rightAnchor).active = true
    
focusGuide.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(btClick.widthAnchor, multiplier: 8).active = true
focusGuide.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(btClick.heightAnchor).active = true
```

Now the guide look like this:
[image]

I've just committ the changes to github maybe it helps anyone else.